# cannot use google or tools on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, or-tools

I am trying to solve a VRP using google or tools. I use java for my program and everything works fine locally.
After deploying the program on lambda I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'

2021-08-13T12:40:59.915+04:00   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkUri(Unknown Source)

2021-08-13T12:40:59.915+04:00   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)

2021-08-13T12:40:59.915+04:00   at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)

2021-08-13T12:40:59.915+04:00   at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)

2021-08-13T12:40:59.916+04:00   at com.google.ortools.Loader.unpackNativeResources(Loader.java:88)

2021-08-13T12:40:59.916+04:00   at com.google.ortools.Loader.loadNativeLibraries(Loader.java:106)
```

this is caused by `Loader.loadNativeLibraries()` method call.

I built the `jar` package using maven with shade plugin.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 if that is related.

I use `com.google.ortools:ortools-java`

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE :
I manually downloaded native library files and put the full path with `System.load(path)` . This gave the following error when executing on Lambda

```
Can't load library: /var/task/src/main/resources/darwin-x86-64/libjniortools.so: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/task/src/main/resources/darwin-x86-64/libjniortools.so
```

Comment: You don't give any information about how you're building and deploying, so it's impossible to give a definitive answer. However, I suspect that you're building on Windows, which uses a different native library. If so, you'll need to build with a Linux-compatible version.

Comment: @kdgregory thank you for reaching out. I updated the description

Comment: And your dependency specification is?

Comment: You're trying to load a Darwin (MacOS) library, which won't be available on Lambda. That's why I asked you to show your dependency config.

Comment: This package includes a native library that is specific to the environment where it's deployed. For a Lambda deployment you'll need to specify the Linux bundle (assuming that there's only one). If you develop on Windows or a Mac, you'll need to specify the bundle that's appropriate for your development environment. In other words, you'll need multiple builds for development and deployment.